# UITableView section index titles too wide for list

Tags: ios, uitableview, indexing

Is there a way to increase the width of the section index titles displayed along the edge of a table view? In my current code some of the titles are being clipped on the left and right:

[image: UITableView with section index titles, some titles clipped on left and right]

I'm not doing anything special in creating the list, just returning an NSArray filled with sorted NSStrings.

Comment: More information: The table above is a standard multi-section table. Another table I have has a single section but I add a section index list to it and handle taps on that list myself, scrolling to the selected row. In this table, the index list IS wide enough to show the widest string! This is just the opposite of what I would expect: the standard multi-section-table-wish-index-list has problems, the non-standard single-section-table-with-index-list does not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my section index titles.
Not sure if this is the correct way, what worked for me was adding:

```
[self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
```

before calling

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

jb

Comment: Alas, this did not solve the problem for me. The index titles remain clipped in iOS 7. (They always worked as expected in previous iOS versions.) What does work (kludge!) is to put a widest index title at the start or end of the list, such as three space chars, and then ignore taps on these 'invisible' titles. Apparently iOS 7 does not test the width of every index title, just those near the start/end of the list. Clearly a bug, IMHO.

Comment: Further info: I put up an empty table at first, then fill it with sections and rows when the data arrives from the server. My 'invisible title' kludge only works if I add it the first time -sectionIndexTitlesForTableView: is called. If I wait until the data arrives, the kludge does nothing. Apparently that first list of titles determines the maximum width for displaying titles; later versions of the list don't change this. In fact, I can skip the kludge in those later versions; as long as it was in the first version this kludge keeps the titles column wide for all later versions.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

Turns out it's enough to return a single empty string the first time `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:` is called, even if the real titles (when the data eventually arrives and the table is reloaded) will be wider.

Only if the initial call returns an empty list does the column for section index titles fail to adjust its width to fit the titles when they arrive.

Answer (score 0):

Reload TableView and it should fix the issue,

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

**iOS 8**

I have that problem in iOS8 too.

This seems to be a bug in iOS8, which is not corrected at the time this post is written (10/2014).

Searching around I found two workarounds.

The first one is to force a reload of the data in the `viewDidAppear`. This will also correct the problem of self-sizing cells not working on first load.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

However in my case it was not solving the issue because I used to change the section index titles after `viewDidAppear`

So the second workaround is simply to `realoadData()` twice

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
self.tableView.reloadData()
```